Turn on FIPS Mode with Tomcat 9.0.93, JVM 17, Windows Server 2022
Turn on FIPS Mode with Tomcat 9.0.93, JVM 17, Windows Server 2022
When I change my server.xml file to:
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" FIPSMode="on"/>

I get an error:
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.736 INFO \[main\] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library \[2.0.8\] using APR version \[1.7.4\].
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.736 INFO \[main\] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 \[true\], sendfile \[true\], accept filters \[false\], random \[true\], UDS \[true\].
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.736 INFO \[main\] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector \[false\], useOpenSSL \[true\]
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.736 SEVERE \[main\] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Failed to initialize the SSLEngine.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The FIPS provider must be configured as the default provider when the AprLifecycleListener is configured with FIPS mode \[on\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL(AprLifecycleListener.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:121)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:709)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.745 SEVERE \[main\] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Failed to enter FIPS mode
java.lang.Error: Failed to enter FIPS mode
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:121)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:709)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
09-Sep-2024 12:28:28.745 SEVERE \[main\] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Error initializing Catalina
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component \[StandardServer\[-1\]\]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:709)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Failed to enter FIPS mode
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:121)
... 8 more

I believe I need to get my JVM to enable FIPS but I tried the following in the java.security file but it didn't help:
security.provider.1=com.rsa.jsafe.provider.JsafeJCE
security.provider.2=com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider
security.provider.3=SUN
security.provider.4=SunRsaSign
security.provider.5=SunEC
security.provider.6=SunJSSE
security.provider.7=SunJCE
security.provider.8=SunJGSS
...
....

I've searched and read a ton of articles but with all the different versions, I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  How do I know exactly which part of the process still needs FIPS Mode enabled?
I know it has to be enabled in:

Tomcat --> doing this gives an error
OS ---> Checked windows and it is on and default
JVM Java ---> thought I enabled it but don't really know how to find out.


Aren't the Jsafe providers commercial products you have pay for? Do you have them?

Very good question.  It didn't say to purchase or download anything on the article I read.   It mentions JCE being bundled.  But maybe it's not the Jsafe products, I'll have to look into it more.

How can you tell if the Jsafe providers are installed?  Should I look at the Bouncy Castle FIPS provider?

Since I can't find Jsafe and they seem to be a part of Oracle WebLogic which I don't have, I'm trying to go the Bouncy Castle FIPS route, but still get the same error after configuring Bouncy Castle, correctly I think!

I added the following to c:\program files\Java\jdk-17\conf\security\java.security
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS security.provider.3=sun.security.provider.Sun
I then put the bc*.jar files in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\lib.
added the following to my Java Options in my Tomcat config:
-Djava.security.properties=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\conf\security\java.security
I still get the same error.
